# Issue of firebug in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am using Firefox3.6.13 and firebug1.6.1.
I can't see any script in firebug plugin, and I can't debug it. But this function would usally works fine in previous version.

Comment: works for me, same versions, you try options-> reset all firebug options, and or uninstall-reinstall

Comment: Sure,I enabled script tag. And reset all options didn't work

Comment: works for me too. What does it say?

Comment: A screenshot would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem persists after Firefox restart, you can also try to create a new fresh Firefox profile (see Firebug FAQ: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ) and install only Firebug extension. This way you avoid possible profile corruption (happens relatively often) and/or collisions with other installed extensions (if any).

Honza

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's time for the classic, **“restart and see if it works now”** solution.

I've had a number of times where firebug decides to quit on me. Just close FireFox completely and restart it. If that doesn't work, you can try reinstalling the addon.

You'll have to give more of a context as to when this issue arose, and what you are/were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

there's also a handy add-on which adds Restart to your File menu. I use this a lot as I find that Firebug ramps up memory usage after a while. A separate add-on StatusBarEx displays memory usage in the status bar so I can keep an eye on it.